# OpenVINO API & samples

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети, openvino

Есть такая библиотека OpenVINO от Intel, предназначена для работы с нейронными сетями.

Пытаясь с ней разобраться, пришлось столкнуться с проблемой - информации о том, как работать с библиотекой очень мало. Представленные примеры довольно запутанны, в них присутствуют сложные связи, много define'ов, код почти не прокомментирован. Примеры явно не минимальны. А многие примеры с сайта даже странички не имеют (404 вылетает).

Посему возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Есть ли где-нибудь описание API упомянутой библиотеки в стиле "вот вам функция - вот описание, что она делает"?
2. Где можно взять минимальный пример для работы с этой библиотекой? То есть ситуация такова - у меня есть обученная нейроная сеть, у которой на входе изображение, нужно написать программу, которая прогоняет через эту сетку конкретный bmp файл. Чем меньше в примере будет зависимостей, тем лучше.

Comment: *Есть ли где-нибудь описание API упомянутой библиотеки в стиле "вот вам функция - вот описание, что она делает"?* - оно есть на оф сайте.  *То есть ситуация такова - у меня есть обученная нейроная сеть, у которой на входе изображение, нужно написать программу, которая прогоняет через эту сетку конкретный bmp файл.* - зачем вам тогда эта библиотека?

Comment: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/annotated.html - это оно? Там всё довольно печально, например найти функцию StartAsync быстро не удалось. А зачем эта библиотека - она разве не это делает? Запускает уже обученную сеть на конкретных данных?

Comment: *найти функцию StartAsync быстро не удалось* - как это так? Там же моментальный поиск, все проиндексировано. "Обученная сеть" предполагает, что она находится в работоспособном состоянии, то бишь имеет надлежащий программный интерфейс и может принимать данные для обработки и / или дообучения. Если у вас есть только какой-нибудь дамп из коэффициентов, то это, скажем так, полуфабрикат, который еще необходимо довести до кондиции. Причем есть ненулевая вероятность, что довести и вообще хоть как-то использовать его можно будет только с использованием инструментов, с помощью которых он был создан.

Comment: Виноват, поиск прошёл, я просто несколько страниц смотрел, и на других поиск не сработал, а эту только просмотрел глазами. Для меня обученная сеть это просто архитектура+коэффициенты, возможно это противоречит общепринятой терминологии. И я так понял, библиотека позволяет как раз создать интерфейс для передачи данных в сетку на обработку.